# is it possible to write an ant target that invokes a java function?

Tags: java, ant

How do you write an ant target that takes a file as input and replaces all white space ' ' characters with '' (i.e. I need an ant target to "minify" the input text file and write it to disk)?

I know that in Java it's a simply doing something like this:

```
public void minify(String originalString){
    String minifiedFile = originalString.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

But how do I get an ant target to invoke "minify()" function and how do I pass in a parameter "originalString" in Ant?

Would appreciate all / any advise.

Comment: It typically works the other way around: you implement a custom task for Ant in Java. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html.

Comment: If `sed` is an option (ie you're on Linux or Mac) it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Ant-Contrib's [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) tag?  That will perform a 'regex-replace' on a given string.

However, it sounds like you may be trying to do that to a whole file, in which case I would write an entire Java program (not just a single function) and invoke that program with ant's built-in [`Java`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task.

Alternatively, as @jahroy suggested in the comments, you could use Ant's built-in [`exec`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to invoke [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).  That's actually probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Recent version of ant support regular [expression based string replacemen](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)t. 
Here is code example from ant site

```
<replaceregexp match="\s+" replace=" " flags="g" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

For the original question - yes.  You can extend ant by

- 1)  [Writing ant tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)
- 2)  [Calling java program](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)
- 3)  [Calling any    program, including platform specific ones](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)
- 4)  [Scripts](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html)

Option 3 (calling programs like sed) will cause problems in the long term maintenance of build environment, though